# SQLServer 2008 - Configuring Service Broker between instances

Tags: sql-server, auditing, service-broker

I've been using the scripts from [this website](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/centralized-asynchronous-auditing-across-instances-and-servers-with-service-broker) to help configure Service Broker based auditing. The first stage - setting up SB between databases on the same instance works fine.

But then, when I try to apply Service Broker between instances, I'm running into grief.

I'm using the command line tool, ssbdiagnose to help me find the config errors:

```
ssbdiagnose -E CONFIGURATION FROM SERVICE tcp://192.168.0.220:4022/Trial/Audit/DataSender -S sqlserver1 -d Trial TO SERVICE //Audit/DataWriter -d MasterAuditDatabase -S devmachine1 ON CONTRACT //Audit/Contract ENCRYPTION OFF
```

which is reporting

> An internal exception occurred: Input string was not in a correct format.

Now this is just checking the config, I haven't even got to the point where I'm sending a message, so the "Input String" must be part of the configuration, but the error message doesn't say where the error occurred and I can't find anything online about diagnosing ssbdiagnose errors.

Can anyone with experience of ssbdiagnose help me understand where the error is, and what I need to do to fix it?

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the service names and contract names in quotes:

```
ssbdiagnose -E CONFIGURATION 
FROM SERVICE "tcp://192.168.0.220:4022/Trial/Audit/DataSender"
 -S sqlserver1 -d Trial 
TO SERVICE "//Audit/DataWriter"
 -d MasterAuditDatabase -S devmachine1 
ON CONTRACT "//Audit/Contract" ENCRYPTION OFF
```